# Select item in JList using code

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I want to be able to write a statement that manually selects an item in a JList, such as:

```
JList myList = new JList(items);
myList.selectValueAt(index);
```

Answer (score 4):

Documentation of JList:

> The selection state of a JList is managed by another separate model, an instance of ListSelectionModel. JList is initialized with a selection model on construction, and also contains methods to query or set this selection model. **Additionally, JList provides convenient methods for easily managing the selection. These methods, such as setSelectedIndex and getSelectedValue, are cover methods that take care of the details of interacting with the selection model.** By default, JList's selection model is configured to allow any combination of items to be selected at a time; selection mode MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION. The selection mode can be changed on the selection model directly, or via JList's cover method. Responsibility for updating the selection model in response to user gestures lies with the list's ListUI.

In your case:

```
myList.setSelectionIndex(index);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the [`ListSelectionModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html) from the `JList`. With that, you can modify the selection:

```
...
ListSelectionModel sm = myList.getSelectionModel();
sm.clearSelection();                     // clears the selection
sm.setSelectionInterval(index, index);   // Sets a selection interval
...
```

While the `ListSelectionModel` allows fine grained control over the selection behaviour of the `JList`,  `JList` itself also provides convenient methods like [`JList.setSelectedIndex()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setSelectedIndex-int-) to simply modify the selected elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
jList.setSelectedValue(string, rootPaneCheckingEnabled)
```

or

```
jList.setSelectedIndex(index);
```